# Nginx VIP ip address redirecting me to wrong destination

Tags: nginx, ssl, nginx-reverse-proxy, keep-alive

I'm currently running Nginx as a reverse proxy for two applications: RocketChat and JFrog. At the moment, I've configured:

1. RocketChat IP: **192.168.141.150** (DNS: **rocket1.tec.local**)
2. JFRog IP: **192.168.141.160** (DNS: **jfrog1.tec.local**)
3. Nginx Keepalive VIP for RocketChat: **192.168.141.155** (DNS: **rocket.tec.local**)
4. Nginx Keepalive VIP for JFrog: **192.168.141.165** (DNS: **jfrog.tec.local**)

When I visit **https://rocket.tec.local**, it redirects me to **rocket1.tec.local** (which is correct and intended). However, when I navigate to **https://192.168.141.155**, I'm taken to **jfrog.tec.local**. Additionally, I encounter an SSL warning indicating that the certificate's common name is **jfrog.tec.local**.

I've attempted some troubleshooting, but the error persists.

1. I generated new CA certificates to determine if the certificate was the problem.
2. I checked and verified nginx.conf

I am not too sure what is wrong.